# Reformatting excel layout

Tags: vba, excel

I'm hoping that I can explain this well enough.
I have an excel document which has been laid out as such;

```
     A      B      C      D     ...     n
1 [     ][  H  ][  H  ][  H  ][ ... ][  H  ]
2 [     ][  T  ][  T  ][  T  ][ ... ][  T  ]
3 [  C  ][  D  ][  D  ][  D  ][ ... ][  D  ]
4 [  C  ][  D  ][  D  ][  D  ][ ... ][  D  ]
5 [  C  ][  D  ][  D  ][  D  ][ ... ][  D  ]
. [ ... ][ ... ][ ... ][ ... ][ ... ][  D  ]
n [  C  ][  D  ][  D  ][  D  ][  D  ][  D  ]
```

H: Major header
T: Title
C: Side Header
D: Data (Some may also be blank)

I need to convert this into a format that can be utilised by a database. I know what I want to convert it to, but I do not know how to do it (with vba or any other alternative).
What I would like is;

```
     A      B      C      D
1 [  C  ][  T  ][  H  ][  D  ]
2 [  C  ][  T  ][  H  ][  D  ]
3 [  C  ][  T  ][  H  ][  D  ]
. [ ... ][ ... ][ ... ][ ... ]
n [  C  ][  T  ][  H  ][  D  ]
```

How I think it could be done is to loop through the viable region (all of the 'Data' represented as 'D'), checking to make sure that is contains data in it (if not do not print that line), and then getting its respective headers and printing out the end products, either by overwriting the previous data or putting it onto a different sheet.

Thanks! Any help is appreciated.

Comment: do you need to do it often or only once?

Comment: If I understand what you're asking, I think only once.

Comment: At first, I was thinking of using formulas but it was even easier with VBA so you can eventually use it as many times as you need :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

here is a full working code (in my sample at least):

```
Option Explicit

Sub convert_for_DB()
Dim lLastRow As Long, lLastCol As Long
Dim c As Range
Dim index As Long
Dim aH As Variant, aT As Variant, aC As Variant
Dim vValues() As Variant

With Worksheets("Sheet1")
    'find the last row and the last col
    lLastCol = .Cells(1, .Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft).Column
    lLastRow = .Cells(.Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row
    'get the headers
    aH = .Range("B1", .Cells(1, lLastCol)).Value
    aT = .Range("B2", .Cells(2, lLastCol)).Value
    aC = .Range("A3", .Cells(lLastRow, 1)).Value
    'create an array with the number of values
    ReDim vValues((lLastRow - 2) * (lLastCol - 1), 3)

    index = 0
    'parse every value of the array
    For Each c In .Range("B3", .Cells(lLastRow, lLastCol))
        If Len(c.Value) > 0 Then
            vValues(index, 0) = aC(c.Row - 2, 1)
            vValues(index, 1) = aH(1, c.Column - 1)
            vValues(index, 2) = aT(1, c.Column - 1)
            vValues(index, 3) = c.Value
            index = index + 1
        End If
    Next c
End With

'store back the data to another sheet
With Worksheets("Sheet2")
    .Range("A1", .Cells(UBound(vValues, 1), 4)) = vValues
End With
End Sub
```

Comment: There was a slight bit missing (Sorry, I've only been able to test it out now). How would it do the "checking if it has data in it", some of the Data blocks have no value. If it has no value I do not want it printed.

Comment: I've made a slight change to check if the cell is empty. I couldn't tested right here. I hope it works fine.

Comment: It was better thanks :) Although it leaves blank lines (Sorry if my original question wasn't clear enough, I will edit it).

Comment: Are you sure your edit works better (i.e. moving the index within the `If`)? Does it leave *every* blank line or only some?

Comment: When I ran it with the index increment within the If, it appeared to work exactly as I wanted it to (probably by some miracle). The index (as far as I can see) is what is responsible for the row positioning.

Answer (score 2):

This should work (it is quick and dirty so not necessarily usable if the setup is not exactly as described in your question) - you need to replace Sheet1 and Sheet2 by the actual sheet names.

```
Public Sub runMeOnce()

  Dim sourceSheet As String
  Dim destinationSheet As String
  Dim i As Long
  Dim j As Long
  Dim destinationRow As Long
  Dim originalData As Variant
  Dim destinationData As Variant

  sourceSheet = "Sheet1"
  destinationSheet = "Sheet2"

  originalData = Sheets(sourceSheet).UsedRange
  ReDim destinationData(1 To (UBound(originalData, 1) - 2) * (UBound(originalData, 2) - 1) + 1, 1 To 4) As Variant

  destinationData(1, 1) = "Side Header"
  destinationData(1, 2) = "Title"
  destinationData(1, 3) = "Header"
  destinationData(1, 4) = "Data"

  destinationRow = 2
  For i = 3 To UBound(originalData, 1)
    For j = 2 To UBound(originalData, 2)
      destinationData(destinationRow, 1) = originalData(i, 1)
      destinationData(destinationRow, 2) = originalData(2, j)
      destinationData(destinationRow, 3) = originalData(1, j)
      destinationData(destinationRow, 4) = originalData(i, j)
      destinationRow = destinationRow + 1
    Next j
  Next i

  Sheets(destinationSheet).Cells(1, 1).Resize(UBound(destinationData, 1), UBound(destinationData, 2)) = destinationData

End Sub
```

Comment: intersting. Another coding style but posted on the very same time. Actually, I don't really like using `UsedRange` because I find it dangerous. Nice shot btw (and +1)

Comment: I agree, I generally don't use it either but thought it would be good enough in this case. +1'ed yours too :)

Answer (score 2):

Well it looks like these other fine folks have beaten me to the punch, but here's my version:

```
Sub FormatData()
    Dim newRowCount
    Dim currentCell
    Dim startCell
    Dim numDataRows
    Dim numDataCols
    Dim i
    Dim j

    newRowCount = 0
    numDataRows = Sheet1.UsedRange.Rows.Count - 2
    numDataCols = Sheet1.UsedRange.Columns.Count - 1

    Set startCell = Sheet1.Cells(3, 2)

    For i = 0 To numDataRows - 1
        For j = 0 To numDataCols - 1
            Set currentCell = startCell.Offset(i, j)
            If startCell.Offset(i, j) <> "" Then
                newRowCount = newRowCount + 1
                Sheet2.Cells(newRowCount, 1).Value = Sheet1.Cells(currentCell.Row, 1).Value
                Sheet2.Cells(newRowCount, 2).Value = Sheet1.Cells(2, currentCell.Column).Value
                Sheet2.Cells(newRowCount, 3).Value = Sheet1.Cells(1, currentCell.Column).Value
                Sheet2.Cells(newRowCount, 4).Value = currentCell.Value
            End If
        Next j
    Next i
End Sub
```

Comment: The three of us answered quickly :). Regarding the performance, your code could be slightly improved (using `With`, using an Array...). Besides, your variable declaration isn't correct because you don't specify the type. Please don't hesitate to have a look at the other answers for some inspiration.